# When do you use polyurethane vs. water based construction adhesive?

Tags: adhesive, construction, polyurethane

When do you prefer to use something like Loctite PL, vs Loctite Power Grab?

[image: PL]
[image: Power Grab]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Water based adhesives have the following disadvantages:

- Slower drying than solvent based adhesives
- Susceptible to freezing at low temperatures.
- Lower water resistance than solvent-based products.

On the other hand, disadvantages of solvent based adhesives:

- Cost – solvent based adhesives are more expensive than water-based adhesives.
- Cleaning: Residues from solvent-adhesive spillages will not come off with water.

Note, albeit the disadvantages, the prevalent sentiment is that the water based adhesive can be used in almost all circumstances without significant downside.

Answer (score 4):

I use water-based (project or panel) adhesive on foam board or any plastic which the solvent will dissolve, or where cleanup of spills is a concern. Solvent-based (heavy duty) for almost everything else. It dries faster and holds better.

Comment: Notably, exposure to moisture is not a reason to choose one over the other, right?

Comment: You mean after installation? I'd expect solvent-based to do better regardless.